# Trim Sheets are they possible in blender?

Tags: texturing, uv, geometry

Can trim sheets be made in blender?. And if so does anyone know of a tutorial on them, the ones i have come across all seem to be for 3DS Max.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is nothing limiting to a particular modelling program with that workflow. Sure, there are differences how you would do different things but if you have good knowledge in Blender these steps could easily be transferred.